# Wrapping text around a lightbulb image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So as the title says. I have some text including a image. I want to wrap it around the sides of the lightbulb image on even if the text is right aligned or left aligned with regard to the image.

This is the HTML:

```
<img id="bulb_section_a" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" src="img/bulb_sec_a.png" />
<img src="img/bulb_sec_a_img.png" /> <span id="title_a">LEARN</span>
<br/> <span style="display: inline-block; width: 100px;"><strong>Lorizzle brizzle dolizzle crazy</strong> get down get down, consectetizzle dawg elit.</span>

<br/>
<img id="bulb_section_b" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" src="img/bulb_sec_b.png" />
<br/>
<img id="bulb_section_c" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" src="img/bulb_sec_c.png" />
<br/>
<img id="bulb_section_d" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" src="img/bulb_sec_d.png" />
```

It's using bootstrap. And here's the CSS: ^(inline :P)

This is the output that is coming:

[image: unexpectedoutput]

How can keep the images in the same place like this:

[image: expectedoutput]

And wrap the text around them?

**Remember: I cannot merge the images into one because they all have their own click effects. :)**

Comment: you can use a single image and for clicking you can use [image maps](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/s/u/summerstyle/365ccfd644f2b008c33f0046d2ba1a8f/summer-html-image-ma_1355318513_demo_package/index.html)

Comment: @TusharGupta your image mapper is not working. :/

Comment: okay use http://www.image-maps.com/

Comment: Or you can try the Bacon jquery plugin: http://baconforme.com/ :)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui What is width of images? What is width of page on either side of images? Want text to left or right side of images?